# Plot a 2D grid data from dict in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to plot a 2D grid (24x4) where each grid coordinates have a value, the data is in a dict as such:

```
{map1_ID:[
             ['x_coor','y_coor','data_to plot'],
             ['x_coor','y_coor','data_to plot'],
             ...
         ],
  map2_ID:[
             ['x_coor','y_coor','data_to plot'], 
             ['x_coor','y_coor','data_to plot'],
             ...
          ]}
```

[image]

How can I do that using matplotlib or any other library in python?

Comment: try `matplotlib.pyplot.matshow()`, here's the docs for it: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html. once you give it a go, if you are still having trouble, let us know with a more focused question about what isn't working with what you are trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly is my go-to for any kind of figure. This is a rough version of what you're looking for.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

maps = {'map1_ID': [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 10], [0, 3, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 14], [1, 3, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 10], [2, 3, 1], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 10], [3, 3, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 1], [4, 2, 10], [4, 3, 1], [5, 0, 1], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 10], [5, 3, 1], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 1], [6, 2, 10], [6, 3, 1], [7, 0, 1], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 10], [7, 3, 1], [8, 0, 1], [8, 1, 1], [8, 2, 10], [8, 3, 1], [9, 0, 1], [9, 1, 1], [9, 2, 10], [9, 3, 1], [10, 0, 1], [10, 1, 1], [10, 2, 12], [10, 3, 1], [11, 0, 1], [11, 1, 1], [11, 2, 10], [11, 3, 1], [12, 0, 1], [12, 1, 1], [12, 2, 10], [12, 3, 1], [13, 0, 1], [13, 1, 1], [13, 2, 10], [13, 3, 1], [14, 0, 1], [14, 1, 1], [14, 2, 10], [14, 3, 1], [15, 0, 1], [15, 1, 1], [15, 2, 10], [15, 3, 1], [16, 0, 1], [16, 1, 1], [16, 2, 10], [16, 3, 1], [17, 0, 1], [17, 1, 1], [17, 2, 10], [17, 3, 1], [18, 0, 1], [18, 1, 1], [18, 2, 10], [18, 3, 1], [19, 0, 1], [19, 1, 1], [19, 2, 10], [19, 3, 1], [20, 0, 1], [20, 1, 1], [20, 2, 10], [20, 3, 1], [21, 0, 1], [21, 1, 1], [21, 2, 10], [21, 3, 1], [22, 0, 1], [22, 1, 1], [22, 2, 10], [22, 3, 1], [23, 0, 1], [23, 1, 1], [23, 2, 10], [23, 3, 1]]}

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(x=[x[0] for x in maps['map1_ID']],
                                y=[x[1] for x in maps['map1_ID']],
                                z=[x[2] for x in maps['map1_ID']],
                                text=[x[2] for x in maps['map1_ID']],
                                texttemplate="%{text}",
                                textfont={"size":20},
                                hoverongaps = False,
                                colorscale=['lime','red','red']
                                )
                )

fig.update_layout(height=300,
                  width=1000)
```

[image]